# 1920x1080 Touchscreen driver (Dell S2240T)

Tags: drivers, raspberry-pi, touchscreen

I'm working on an interactive infoscreen-system based on a raspberry Pi 3. For that I need to install the LCD-show driver to the Pi in order to use it as a touchscreen. But the screen I have to use has a 1920 x 1080 resolution and it's a Dell S2240T 21.5'.

I haven't found a way to get the driver for this resolution. And the drivers for other resolutions won't work.
Is there somekind of an alternative?

Comment: I’m not quite sure what you’re expecting to find. Sounds like a plain old PC display to me. It probably connects via HDMI and doesn’t require any drivers whatsoever.

Comment: It's a Dell S2240T touchscreen monitor. Yes its connected with a HDMI but also with a USB for the touchscreen signal.The driver I'm searching is just for the touchinput.

Comment: What you’re looking for isn’t Pi-specific in any way. I’ve never used a touchscreen with Linux, so I cannot provide further assistance, sorry.

Comment: Have a look at this discussion: [Enabling USB Touchscreen](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=116174)

Comment: Drivers are for devices, not for resolutions.

Comment: Indeed, the touchscreen is independent of resolutions and it must be able to work best at its native resolution. There are no drivers bundled by Dell because it's assumed to be "plug'n'play" (USB) and it is for any Windows 7 (updated) or newer, MacOS (?), and any desktop Linux distro since several years ago. Provided the computer has USB and runs an OS supporting it it doesn't matter if it's RPi or a desktop PC. The driver you may need to find to make it work depends on the OS. Please [edit] and add that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I now used the driver from [git](https://github.com/bsteinsbo/rpi_touch_driver). It works perfectly fine with the Dell Monitor and the desired resolution.